# Xamarin AccountStore/Account not persisting when app is updated

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm using the Xamarin AccountStore/Account to hold information about the user of my application (their details are stored after they have been authenticated by a remote server)

This works fine if the details are written out, the app killed and then restarted. It finds the existing account store.

However if the app is updated (because I make some changes in Xamarin Studio and redeploy) then it doesn't find any accounts for my service.

This is how I'm requesting the account:

```
var accountStore = AccountStore.Create(this._context);
var storage = accountStore.FindAccountsForService(this._serviceId);
var account = storage.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == username);
```

And this is how I'm persisting the account settings:

```
accountStore.Save(account, this._serviceId);
```

Does anyone know why the AccountStore is not found when the app is updated?

Any idea where it's being stored on the device?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm also having the same issue and looking for the solution

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832940/xamarin-auth-account-data-not-persisted-when-app-is-updated), checking Preferences --> Android --> check "Preserve data/cache between application deploys" fixes the problem.